# VBA to filter all months w/ year in date column

Tags: vba, excel

I am on this project that I need to filter out all the months with year in the date column. For example, all the January 2017 dates are filtered out and copy to new sheet, all February 2017 dates are filtered out and copy to new sheet, and so on. Is it possible in VBA? I don't have code yet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is definitely possible. Try to do the following -> 1. Filter the dates. 2. Create a new sheet. 3. Paste the dates on the new sheet.

Comment: My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" what should I put on criteria regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: Simply record a macro and check it out -> It would be there.

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$V$31647").AutoFilter Field:=13, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "1/31/2017") - this what macro return. I'll be needing all months so I guess it should loop from January-December.

Comment: You are doing good, Mark! :)

Comment: So you mean I need to record macro for all the months?

Comment: You can do it. Then you can compare the differences in the code and think what you can do to make it better. Then read about Loops and how they function. https://www.google.com/search?q=loop+vba&oq=loop+vba&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i60l3j0.1416j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8